# Laravel: How to store value that is displayed and selected in dropdown field as input, not the id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-backpack

I use Backpack for Laravel 4.1.

Table: **users**

```
---------------------------
| id |        name        |
---------------------------
| 1  | Rory Choi          |
---------------------------
| 2  | Freddie Farrington |
---------------------------
| 3  | Cristian Wyatt     |
---------------------------
```

Table: **documents**

I want the value that stored in the table to be the value of name from users table, not the id.

I want **this**:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id |     description     |           name           |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Something           | Cristian Wyatt           |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Other thing         | Freddie Farrington       |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    |                     |                          |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**Not this**:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id |     description     |           name           |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Something           | 3                        |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Other thing         | 2                        |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    |                     |                          |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**DocumentController**.php:

It does show the list of names from users table, but it does not store the name value

```
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::addField([
        'label'     => 'Username',
        'name'      => 'username',
        'type'      => 'select2',
        'entity'    => 'users', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    ]);
}
```

**Document**.php

The method that defines the relationship.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User','name','name');
}
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of name field why don't you make a relation to that users table ? it is more logical to have relation by ID to users and to get the name from there (up to date in case of changes) ? So documents.name  > documents.user_id

Comment: @Svetoslav I am understand, but somehow I don't want that way. If it can't be done then maybe I just try that way. Thank you.

Comment: Relations by ID instead of copying attributes from table 1 to table 2 is a lot better approach. At that case I think that you are in the wrong way. If tomorrow you decide to set email will you copy it as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my question.

I need to add this line to user model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

And change primary key to name:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'name';
```

FYI: This is only **an example**, I know that using name as primary key is not right. I think I can use it for something like username or another unique key (not incrementing one).

Thanks.

Reference: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/179#issuecomment-486684173

Answer (score 0):

relationship not work for that you can use this method.

use that :

```
public function users()
{
    return User::where('name',$this->name)->first();
}
```

instead of

```
public function users()

    {
        return $this->hasOne('User','name','name');
    }
```

Comment: i tried change the method in controller but i got error, do i need to change the attributes inside addField() in setupCreateOperation?

Comment: delete attribute foreign key of 'name'